# Is there any other way to create an application in google app engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I want to create an application in google app engine using php,
Is there any way to login in to my google account using php and create an application dynamically.

Comment: What would be the point?  You only have 10 apps anyway... automating the process of using those 10 seems like a waste of time to me.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, the only way I know to create an app engine app via PHP is through [Quercus](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/), the PHP implementation on top of the JVM, as per [this post](http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/run-php-on-the-google-app-engine/).

**Edit**: that was "create an app" in the sensible sense of the words -- the running code, simple configuration, data files, &c, that together make up an app -- back when the question was short and ambiguous.

As the question has now been clarified as being instead a quest to violate google's [terms and conditions](http://code.google.com/appengine/terms.html) by automating an administrative operation in breach of section 2.3 ("""2.3. You agree not to (a) access (or attempt to access) the administrative interface of the Service by any means other than through the interface that is provided by Google in connection with the Service"""), the case is very different -- my response to *that* request I'll leave in a comment on this answer.

Comment: i dont want to run php on google app engine.
i want to create application using php.

Comment: @Alex Martelli did u understood my question?

Comment: Oh, I see, you want to automate steps that Google wants you to keep manual, i.e., you want to violate google's terms and conditions. It's technically possible, for a while, if you use a method no googler has yet thought about (since I'm a googler, any suggestion from me couldn't possibly be ones no googler has yet thought about;-), then google will find out, block your chosen attack vector, rinse, repeat (until you give up or the FBI gets interested, as it finally has recently in spam email). Programming language choice's not the key issue here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Google provides no way to automatically create apps on their App Engine.

But as long as you can do it from a browser, you can simulate the app registering process with http queries, using cURL for instance, in PHP.

cURL allows you to send http queries, optionnally with POST data, cookies, etc...you can also set a user-agent. You can pretty much emulate every browser's behaviours. Here, you will have to make a POST query containing the data you're supposed to have filled in the app registering form.

More on cURL on [the PHP doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), and there's even [a StackOverflow tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/curl) for it.